# Only one site in Whole Web application not displaying usage report

Tags: 2013, site-usage

Recently customer reported of an issue, where usage reports turns out to be empty. Weird thing is only this site collection in that web application affected. All othe sites within that web app are sucessfully generating usage reports. Where do i start troubleshooting from on this case.

Comment: check the site collection quota if it is maxed out? when this site collection was created? runt he site collection health check from site settings?

Comment: Out of total storage only 49.54% storage has been used. Ran the site collection health check, it says "The following files have been customized from their default and may present some unexpected visuals or behavior after upgrade:" and i have about 25 diffrent document templates (dotx,doc) listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Check following

1. permission for the database Wss_logging as described in this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/681b6c53-3969-4984-8a78-4d6e6c55f29c)
2. Actual data is processed during crawling. So if there is no crawler
   scheduled for content sources or there is a problem with the
   crawlers no actual data is processes.
3. Only queries and interaction done by "normal" named users are
   captured. If you access SharePoint using an administrative account
   you queries etc. would not be showmen in the reports.
4. Check whether the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data
   Processing and Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import
   timer jobs are all running
5. Make sure WSS_Admin_WPG and WSS_WPG have access to the log folder.
6. Create a new login in SQL for logging access

   - Go back to Central Admin -> Monitoring -> Configuring health data collection
     use SQL authentication instead of Windows

http://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/enabling-usage-reportsharepoint-2013/